# Installing ImageMagick for C(++) on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, imagemagick

I'm having a hard time installing the ImageMagick software for Ubuntu 12.10.

So, I want the C and C++ API, not much more. Now when I go to imagemagick.org, they have a binary package for unix, namely an rpm. When I download and launch it, RPM complains that firstly I should be using alien, and secondly there are like 10000 missing dependencies. If I use alien to create a deb file, and the install it via the software center, the package does indeed install, but only the command line interface - no includes, anything. Same with apt-get imagemagick. (BTW - wtf, they don't have support for ubuntu?)

I tried compiling from source (which I shoudn't be doing anyway - I'm not expecting much customization am I?), and then the includes are present, but the programs won't compile complaining about "undefined reference" and then a list of everything that isn't pure C (and I'm using the command imagemagick.org told me to use, namely cc -o wand `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand` wand.c) so clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked those API's are not available in the default repositories? Packages like `libmagick++-dev` and `imagemagick` should give you what you need.

Comment: @Salem I've installed magickwand-dev and imagemagick and now I have linker errors, just like after compiling from source:

`thumb.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to \`MagickWandGenesis\`
thumb.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to \`NewMagickWand`
etc etc...

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) (Usage)?

Comment: Yes, it works well for C++ and Magick++, thanks. But MagickWand for C is still giving me errors, and I do what they say here:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php, I'm using this very command to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as you. You'll have to compile with this command:

```
cc -o wand wand.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand`
```

instead of:

```
cc -o wand `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand` wand.c
```